# Rachav line in aleinu

Tags: aleinu-leshabeiach

Someone told me that Rachav wrote a line in Aleinu. Does anyone have the source and know what line it is, or at least know if this is true?

Comment: I've heard that Al Ken Necave was written by Achan, the guy who took booty from Jericho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Indeed, one verse of Aleinu is intimated by Rachav when she says to Yeshoshua’s two spies (Yehoshua 2:9-11), “I know that Hashem has given you the Land because your fear has fallen upon us…. For Hashem your L-rd is the L-rd in the Heavens above and on the earth beneath.”

https://strangeside.com/aleinu-prayer/